Lectures Notes on Maxwell-Jüttner distribution function
I have been looking online for good notes on the application of relativity to statistical mechanics, in particular about the Maxwell-Jüttner distribution function.  Does anyone have some links to share on where I may find good material?
I found this discussion on the topic but unfortunately no link to any material.
